# DataTable assigned to constructor not adding data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have defined a class as following:

```
(function() {
     'use strict';

      function UsersHelper(){
           this.init();
           this.usersTable = null;
      }

      UsersHelper.prototype.init = function(){

         $('#userType').on('change', function(){
              let newData = [{ 'name': 'foo' }];
              this.usersTable.row.add(newData);
         }.bind(this));

         this.initUserTable();
      };

      UsersHelper.prototype.initUserTable = function(){
          this.usersTable = $('#my-dataTable').DataTable({
                columns: [{
                     data: 'name'
                }], 
                destroy: true,
           });

          $('#userType').trigger('change');
      };
});
```

Essentially I've declared in the constructor of the class the field `usersTable` which actually contains the `DataTable` instance, then the `init` method create the `DataTable` and save the instance.

After that the initialization is completed, I trigger the change event on the `userType` which should add the `newData` row to the `usersTable` stored in the class.

The problem's that the data isn't added. I saw that if I declare the variable `usersTable` outside `UsersHelper`, so without use `this.usersTable` all works well.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

> When jQuery calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events
>   this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated
>   events this is an element matching selector. (Note that this may not
>   be equal to event.target if the event has bubbled from a descendant
>   element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be
>   used with jQuery methods, use $( this ).

You issue is caused by wrong `this` scope. Inside `on` handler jQuery binds `this` to the current DOM element which caused current event. So you have to save you class's `this` local scope and then use it instead of `this` inside `on` handler.

```
UsersHelper.prototype.init = function(){
       var that = this; // note this change
       this.initUserTable();
         $('#userType').on('change', function(){
              let newData = [{ 'name': 'foo' }];
              that.usersTable.row.add(newData); // use class context
         });


      };
```

Comment: this isn't working, I tried your solution but as you can see from my code I binded `this` to the event handler. That's weird 'cause if I declare the table without this that works

Comment: Have you tried to debug at this moment value of `that.usersTable`?

Comment: yes, the strange thing is that the instance is actually defined, so I get no problems on this, just the data is not added

Comment: Can you recreate this issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: Huh, finally I resolved it. You forget to use [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())  method after data was added. Accroding to the official doc of [add() method](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) : 

Note that in order to see the new row in the table you must call the draw() method, which is easily done through the chaining that the DataTables API employs.